# How to Freeze 1st column or 1st-nth in Table-View (QuickSight)?

Tags: amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

Need help or alternative way to freeze 1st column or aggregated(group-by) columns. In few tables we have columns count > 60, users can't compare or know to which row (name) they are referring. To increase user experience we need to freeze the 1st column or aggregated(group-by) columns in Table-View. Similar to Freeze-Panes in Excel.

Thanks

Comment: Please add more details for others to help you better.